# C++ map.clear() pure virtual method runtime error

Tags: c++, dictionary, pure-virtual

I believe the problem may stem from using boost::shared_ptrs as key values.

```
//header file:
#include <map>
std::map<boost::shared_ptr<foo>, bar> myMap; // Private member variable

//////////
myMap.insert(pair);
//////////
myMap.clear()
```

Neither foo nor bar are abstract classes.
At which point, during run-time, I will receive a "pure virtual method called" error, and my program will terminate. I've also tried iterating through the map and using myMap.erase(iterator), which produces the same error.

Comment: What's `bar` ? Is it an abstract class ? Or is `foo` an abstract class ?

Comment: Please show us the definitions of `foo` and `bar` and definitions of all base classes of `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: What is `foo` and what is `bar`?

Comment: Perhaps something about the destructor of `foo` or `bar` is doing things in the wrong order?

Comment: Neither class foo nor bar are abstract. It would make my life a lot easier if I could post the full source code, but I'm currently subject to an NDA.

Comment: Take a note that using a pointer type for the key is completely insane idea.

Comment: What is `pair`? How do you create one?

Comment: If neighter foo nor bar are abstract (and you are sure about that - have you tried to instantiate both foo and bar?) then I guess one of Foo or Bar must have a field (or its base class has a field) of type MyClass* where MyClass is abstract. I guess that MyClass calls pure virtual method in destructor which leads to "pure virtual method called". Try to comment out all destructors and uncomment them unless you get your error again (you can use bisection).

Answer (score 1):

If bar is a polymorphic type, when you it could be slicing the class.  Depending on what the destructor is doing, it could then access a pure virtual method.